# Why entity framework is referencing a column that doesn't even exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

My project is throwing error

**Invalid column name 'InitialsID_InitialsID'.**

```
public User ValidateUser(string Username, string Password)
{
    return uow.UserRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.UserName == Username && x.Password == Password).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Even there's no column by that name in the whole solution.

I had generated a migration script and it had that name in it but I changed that to InitialsID but still it asks for the same name.

How do I resolve it? I tried putting ForeignKey attribute etc but nothing works.

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int UserGroupID { get; set; }
    public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool? PasswordExpire { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public string Office { get; set; }

    public string Station { get; set; }

    public Initials InitialsID { get; set; }
}
```

Initials.cs

```
public class Initials
{
    public short InitialsID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Code First approach.

Comment: You are using code first approach?

Comment: yes, CF approach

Comment: I might be mistaken, but shouldn't public Initials InitialsID { get; set; } be rather public virtual Initials Initials { get; set; } and add one more property public short InitialsID {get;set;}

Comment: @PiotrWojsa: hey it worked. But don't know why a virtual did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your foreign key configuration. When you are referencing navigation property `public Initials InitialsID { get; set; }`, EF is adding an implicit foreign key for this navigation property and it is by convention `navigationPropery_navigationPropertyPrimaryKey` and hence it is `InitialsID_InitialsID`

If you really want `public Initials Initials { get; set; }` navigaation property in `User` model class then  write your foreign key configuration as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int UserGroupID { get; set; }

    ......................

    public short InitialsId { get; set; }
    public Initials Initials { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your database not migrated with new model or new models property,
Pleas migrate your database. 
If you are using dotnet core, in cmd on the project folder type:

```
dotnet ef migrations add [name]
```

and then:

```
dotnet ef databae update
```